# Node - Detect if uploaded file is an image - Hapi.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I have a basic defense on the client (React.js) to check for the file and size. That provides small security as the yser can change the extension and upload any file type on the server.

I did this type of checking previously using [Image Magick](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick)  on the Express.js project, and that worked very nicely.

This time, I do not need all of the weapons Image magick providesm just need to make sure that the file is indeed an image. Is there an alternative?

If not, than I will end up using IM, but really would be nice to have some small sized library that just does this.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but have you taken a look at [node-exif](https://github.com/gomfunkel/node-exif)?

Comment: Nice suggestion. I will definitely give it a try :).